# Use SQL to create a text file and save to a varbinary blob file without writing to disk

Tags: sql, sql-server, varbinary

I currently have a working SQL stored procedure that is using BCP and xp_cmdshell to create a text file on the system disk and then upload that file into a varbinary field in an Attachments table.

What I'm needing to know is if it is possible to do this without writing a file to disk as part of the process?

**UPDATED DETAILS**

I am using MSSQL 2014 and the intention is to load the text file (a csv file actually) into the database so that other users can download it.

Comment: Uh, if it's a text file, why not just store the _contents_?  What problem are you trying to solve by storing the file itself?  Among other things, storing the contents allows you to query it, or change line ending based on the receiving platform.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Is the source and target table in the same database? The same server?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes this would be all in the same database and server.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse makes a very good point - why are you doing this? is it because you want to be able to download the file out of the database? Since they are in the same database, does the answer below from Mani Kandan help?

Answer (score 0):

Is Text File is generating only for pusing content into varbinary fields?if so why dont you use simply convert the content directly into varbinary using convert function and push directly the results into table field.

If i am getting wrong correct me pls.